# Illegal conversion from List<ActiveContactListController.ContactsWithRoles> to List<AccountContactRelation>

Tags: apex, error, list

i have this code i getting the error the following error, i'm new to salesforce developer someone can help me?

```
    public class ActiveContactListController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<AccountContactRelation> getContacts(Id recordId) {

        List<AccountContactRelation> ConList = [
            SELECT 
                id, Contact.FirstName,Contact.LastName,Contact.MobilePhone,Roles 
            FROM AccountContactRelation 
            WHERE AccountId =: recordId 
            AND 
            IsActive = true];

        List<ContactsWithRoles> contactsWithRoles;
        for (AccountContactRelation accContRel :ConList)
        {
            ContactsWithRoles contWithRoles = new ContactsWithRoles();
            contWithRoles.accConRelWithRoles = accContRel;
            contWithRoles.roles = accContRel.roles.replace(';',';\n');
            contactsWithRoles.add(contWithRoles);

        }
        **return contactsWithRoles;**
    } 

       public class ContactsWithRoles
       {
           String roles{get; set;}
           AccountContactRelation accConRelWithRoles{get; set;}
       }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your method signature is wrong - it says your method should return a `List<AccountContactRelation>` but your comment says you're returning `List<ContactsWithRoles>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to how Type Systems work.

While your `ActiveContactListController.ContactsWithRoles` object *contains* an `AccountContactRelation` object, it (ContactsWithRoles) is *not* the same as an `AccountContactRelation` object.

The declared return type in your method needs to match (or extend) the type of the variable (or statement) that you actually return. Since we can't extend SObjects, that means you'll need an exact type match.

You'll either need to change your declared return type to `List<ContactsWithRoles>`, or change what you're returning so it is actually a `List<AccountContactRelation>`.